# Android 6 intent-filter for custom files not persistent after restart

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Android 6.0.1 application I have an intent-filter for custom files which my application generates but the intent-filter only works up until I do a restart. After a restart, I get the message: Unable to open file.

In my Android 4.1.2 device I have the same application and intent-filter but it can still access my files after restarts.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gray10.glassshutters">

<uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MCRViewer"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mcr" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the code that handles the intent:

```
public class MCRViewer extends Activity
{
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MCRViewer.this,
             Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

         // Should we show an explanation?
         if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MCRViewer.this,
                 Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

             // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
             // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
             // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

         } else {

             // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MCRViewer.this,
                     new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                     MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

             // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
             // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
             // result of the request.
         }
     }


     setContentView(R.layout.scrolltextview);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXT_ID);
    //text.setText("Text Changed");
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getData().getPath();
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try 
    {
        fr = new FileReader(name);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (null != line) 
        {
            text.append(line);
            text.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (null != br) 
        {
            try 
            {
                br.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        if (null != fr) 
        {
            try 
            {
                fr.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

After some experimenting it would seem that the problem is with Samsung's My Files application.  An alternative file explorer worked ok.

Comment: What do you mean by restart,  and may be you can show us some code for handling the intent to your app

Comment: By restart I mean powering off the device and restarting it.  I have edited my post to show the code for handling the intent.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No.  I now have Android 7.0 and the latest version of My Files and intent filters do not work at all.

Comment: I have just installed the Astro file manager from Google Play Store and this seems to work with intent filters.